# Bash script to iterate through a specific time range, one second at a time

Tags: bash, timestamp

I am trying to create some sort of loop in bash that will iterate through a specific time range, one second at a time.

At each interval, it will perform a duty with that timestamp I.e. "Wed Mar 2 12:00:03 CDT 2018"

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how to make a loop that will iterate every second of time, and when it hits 60 seconds, update the minute, etc.

Thoughts? This seems obvious but the right syntax escapes me.

Comment: elaborate your *a specific time range*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and add sample input and expected output. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 1):

this is one way of doing it, delegate time computations to `date`

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do date -d "+$i seconds"; done

Sun Mar 11 20:40:57 UTC 2018
Sun Mar 11 20:40:58 UTC 2018
Sun Mar 11 20:40:59 UTC 2018
Sun Mar 11 20:41:00 UTC 2018
Sun Mar 11 20:41:01 UTC 2018
Sun Mar 11 20:41:02 UTC 2018
Sun Mar 11 20:41:03 UTC 2018
Sun Mar 11 20:41:04 UTC 2018
Sun Mar 11 20:41:05 UTC 2018
Sun Mar 11 20:41:06 UTC 2018
Sun Mar 11 20:41:07 UTC 2018
```

if you want to iterate up to a certain time, change the for loop to a while loop and a counter.

Answer (score 0):

To make a loop with time you need to format date/time in such a way that can be comparable. The most easy trick is to transform date to something that will look like an integer and you then use `lt`,`le`,`eq`,`gt`,`ge` operators of bash.

Consider this :

```
$ date
Mon Mar 12 00:16:29 EET 2018 #this format/data type is not comparable by bash
$ date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
20180312001629 #this is an integer representing the current time
```

This is a sample loop from now up to a specific time point:

```
stop=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S --date "2018-03-12 00:20:55")
while [[ $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) -le $stop ]];do #comparing current date & time with stop date & time
echo "date now is $(date)";
sleep 1;      #sleep 1 second
done

date now is Mon Mar 12 00:20:51 EET 2018
date now is Mon Mar 12 00:20:52 EET 2018
date now is Mon Mar 12 00:20:53 EET 2018
date now is Mon Mar 12 00:20:54 EET 2018
date now is Mon Mar 12 00:20:55 EET 2018
```

The trick here is that the command

```
stop=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S --date "2018-03-12 00:20:55")
```

converts given date (using the `--date` flag) to a kind of integer format.

Then the `while` loop keeps comparing current `date` in the same integer format with the `stop` date.

This is a similar script to start/stop at a specific time, but it is a bit "resources hungry" since it keeps comparing current time to start time:

```
date;             #just print the current date & time
compl=false;
start=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S --date "2018-03-12 01:45:50");
stop=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S --date "2018-03-12 01:45:55");
while true;do 
 while [[ $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) -ge $start ]] && [[ $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) -le $stop ]];do 
  echo "date now is $(date)";
  sleep 1;
  compl=true;
 done;
 ($compl) && break;
done

Mon Mar 12 01:45:37 EET 2018
date now is Mon Mar 12 01:45:50 EET 2018
date now is Mon Mar 12 01:45:51 EET 2018
date now is Mon Mar 12 01:45:52 EET 2018
date now is Mon Mar 12 01:45:53 EET 2018
date now is Mon Mar 12 01:45:54 EET 2018
date now is Mon Mar 12 01:45:55 EET 2018
```

An alternative to start/stop a script at specific time would be to use  epoch date / epoch seconds.
Epoch date is measured in seconds since the epoch (1970-01-01 UTC).
Every date can be expressed as epoch seconds, using the format `date +%s`.

```
date                         #just print the current date & time
start="2018-03-12 02:17:52"
stop="2018-03-12 02:17:57"
timerequired=$(( $(date +%s --date "$start") - $(date +%s) ))
sleep $(($timerequired))     #sleep till the starting time 
while [[ $(date +%s) -le $(date +%s --date "$stop") ]];do 
  echo "date now is $(date)";
  sleep 1;
done

Mon Mar 12 02:17:39 EET 2018
date now is Mon Mar 12 02:17:52 EET 2018
date now is Mon Mar 12 02:17:53 EET 2018
date now is Mon Mar 12 02:17:54 EET 2018
date now is Mon Mar 12 02:17:55 EET 2018
date now is Mon Mar 12 02:17:56 EET 2018
date now is Mon Mar 12 02:17:57 EET 2018
```

Finally, you can use external tools to automate things based on date & time like `cron`, `anacron` , `at`, etc

Answer (score 0):

Echo a date for every second in a range:

```
from=$(date -d "Wed Mar 2 12:59:58 CDT 2018" +%s) 
to=$(date -d "Wed Mar 2 13:00:04 CDT 2018" +%s) 
for s in $(seq $from $to); do echo $(date -d @$s); done
```

The `date -d` takes a well formed date as input. `+%s` formats it into seconds since epoch. So you get two big values like from=1520013598, to=...3604. The `date -d @1520013598` transforms the timestamp back to a human readable date.

Your range might be in a variable like start and stop, and you might like to foobar ($time) instead of echoing it:

```
start="Wed Mar 2 12:59:58 CDT 2018"
stop="Wed Mar 2 13:00:04 CDT 2018"
from=$(date -d "$start" +%s) 
to=$(date -d "$stop" +%s) 
for s in $(seq $from $to)
do
    timestamp=$(date -d @$s)
    foobar $timestamp
done
```